# What do the last two fields in fstab mean?

Tags: fstab

The last two fields on each line in `fstab` (`dump` and `pass`) are some numbers (usually, `0`).

What do these numbers mean?

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=030ccf66-5195-4835-ba3e-f5d7a5403c05 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Copy/paste from `man fstab`:

> The fifth field, (fs_freq),  is  used  for  these  filesystems  by  the
>   dump(8)  command  to determine which filesystems need to be dumped. 
>   If the fifth field is not present, a value of zero is  returned  and 
>   dump will assume that the filesystem does not need to be dumped.
>
> The  sixth field, (fs_passno), is used by the fsck(8) program to determine
>   the order in which filesystem checks are done at reboot
>   time.  The root  filesystem  should  be specified with a fs_passno of 1, and
>   other filesystems should have a fs_passno of 2.  Filesystems within  a
>   drive will  be checked sequentially, but filesystems on different drives
>   will be checked at the same time to utilize  parallelism  available  in 
>   the hardware.   If  the sixth field is not present or zero, a value of
>   zero is returned and fsck will assume that the filesystem does not 
>   need to be checked.

Comment: But, what does the dump-utility do? (It has no man-page)

Comment: If you don't have a dump man page, then you don't have dump installed. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/dump.8.html - it's for backup purposes.

Comment: @JanC by `check` you mean file system error check ?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/247523/fstab-when-do-you-use-the-dump-and-fsck-options TL;DR: just set dump to zero always, and pass to 1 for root drive, 2 for any other drive.

Comment: @np8 you don't want fsck running on something like a NFS for example, so "2 for any other drive" isn't entirely correct

Answer (score 15):

Simple blockhead answer is , first field determines if it should be dumped, second field determines if it should be checked during startup and in what sequence. Check the manual for the rest!

Comment: Define dump FFS 

Comment: @chx101 see here: https://superuser.com/questions/247523/fstab-when-do-you-use-the-dump-and-fsck-options -- short answer is that 'dump' seems to be rarely used anymore, so you would almost always expect this to be zero. The second number is used by the more widely used fsck to check the filesystem, and if so in what order (root should be 1, rest should increment, or zero to skip checking the filesystem)