# Best way to mount /tmp in fstab?

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab, tmp

What is the best way (options, those numbers on the end) to mount a `/tmp` partition in `/etc/fstab` in terms of *security* and *speed* on a **desktop** (laptop) computer (read: **not server**)?

I've heard about `nosuid`, `nodev` and `noexec`, but I have no idea what they do, how to use them or even if I should used them.

I'm using LVM btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default is just a directory in the root filesystem.

That's fine but I have a desktop, a ton of RAM and reboot very infrequently... Which is the perfect description of somebody who could be using RAM instead of SSD for caching temporary stuff... So mine is mounted as a `tmpfs` RAMdisk, defined in `fstab` as:

```
tmpfs    /tmp    tmpfs    defaults,noatime,mode=1777   0  0
```

If you power cycle lots, this obviously isn't going to be a good idea for you.

You asked on another —now deleted— answer what the two zeroes were on the end, that's [handled by another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9939/what-does-the-last-two-fields-in-fstab-mean) but they basically mean the system doesn't care about what happens to this filesystem if things crash. It won't dump out or check it for errors on boot.

`noatime` is just there as a tiny performance thing. Nothing I know of needs to audit access times of `/tmp` so I don't bother storing them. There's nothing inherently dangerous about allowing SUID, exec or character devices in `/tmp` and some things *might* need them.

In terms of security, while anything can write into `/tmp` it doesn't mean anything can overwrite or even read existing files. If you have a go-rw permission file, other people won't be able to mess around with it. The various systems that write into `/tmp` already do things to make sure that they're not clashing over filenames (typically by appending the `$USER` variable to the filename).

Comment: in Ubuntu 14.04+ tmpreaper http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/tmpreaper.8.html is used by default to clean up /tmp and uses atime to determine age so you would want to update the settings to use ctime if you want it to clean files over time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but it looks like in modern Ubuntu versions, editing `/etc/fstab` doesn't work anymore for `/tmp`. Now it seems to be managed by `systemd`, so to edit its options you should edit the `/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount` file. You could do that with `sudo systemctl edit tmp.mount --full`. Options are given in the `Options` line, like `Options=mode=1777,relatime,nodev,nosuid,noexec`.

Comment: Well, I made that answer based on my expirience. Editing `/etc/fstab` didn't work for me on 20.04, but I found a mention of `tmp.mount` [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061328/171572). So, for me `tmp.mount` systemd unit was the right place, not the `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: One more link about `tmp.mount`: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/tmpfs#Disable_automatic_mount. Although it's for Arch Wiki, it is still about systemd specifics.