# How to mount /tmp to another directory to increase memory

Tags: mount, raid, fstab, tmp

My `/tmp` directory is now at capacity and I want to increase the available memory:

```
df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p3   59G   54G  2.1G  97% /
```

To try and do this, I plan to move my `/tmp` folder to  `/mnt/raid1/tmp` (a mounted directory with a lot more available memory) and following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550589/best-way-to-mount-tmp-in-fstab) I tried adding the following to `etc/fstab`:

```
#update /tmp directory to get increased memory for running processes
/tmp    /mnt/raid1/tmp    defaults,noatime,mode=1777   0  0
```

However this caused an issue after rebooting that was only resloved when I removed these lines. Anybody know how to move `/tmp` to `/mnt/raid1/tmp` correctly?

Comment: That doesn't look right - where's the field specifying the filesystem? Are you trying a bind mount?

Comment: "memory"? As in free up RAM? Not going to happen... /tmp is a dir on disk and will not free up memory. if you mean disk space... /tmp is cleared out on every reboot.  What you ask seems off to me.

Comment: Hi @muru and Rinzwind. Just to mention I'm very new to this so I may not be describing my issue very well. The problem is the current /tmp file is pretty much at capacity so we want to move it to a mounted directory which has a lot more memory. I'll update the question to try make this more clear. muru I wasn't sure what filesystem to specify in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount-bind /tmp to the alternative directory as in:

```
/mnt/raid1/tmp /tmp none bind
```