# Ubuntu runs filesystem check on every boot

Tags: boot, filesystem, fsck

I recently used gparted on the Ubuntu live USB to move/extend my `/` and `/home` partitions. No errors arose but now every time I boot Ubuntu, I get a long filesystem check that I can't skip.

I have used the live USB to run `fsck` on both `/` and `/home` [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237389/ubuntu-20-04-every-boot-makes-a-very-long-filesystem-check) but this made no difference. This question also suggests forcing a skip of the check but I would rather avoid this (and even when I tried this, it didn't stop the check).

What are the next steps I can take to try to resolve this issue?

For reference, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 dual booted with Windows (which boots fine) on an NVMe drive.

To add extra details:
I've checked the Maximum mount count and Check interval for both partitions and these are disabled.

Comment: Is this an installed system in the internal  (nvme) drive? Did you force fsck for example with the following command line, `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p5` (if partition #5)? Was there some warning or error output? Could you repeat the command until there was no error?

Comment: Yes, this is installed and on an internal drive. I forced fsck on both the / and /home partitions and there were no warnings or errors.

Comment: Interestingly when I edit `/etc/fstab` to skip filesystem checks, the checks still happen

Comment: Did you try according to the answer (by @kanehekili)? In that case, what result did you get? (I have one laptop with an nvme drive and I put a pci card with an nvme stick into my main computer; none of them has the kind of problem you describe.)

Comment: I found @kanahekili's answer a bit unclear. I wasn't sure exactly what functionality of the nvme-cli tool to use. The closest from the documentation seemed to be nvme-error-log which returned a clean sweep of passes for both partitions.

It's worth noting that this problem only arose after using gparted (though it appeared to work fine). There were no issues at all up to this point.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood NVMEs are different from the HDD or SDD disks. So `fsck` might not get the results you need.

First you should check the [NVME wearout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565505/wear-of-nvme-ssd-disk-debian) of your "disk".

In addition to that you may have a look at the [nvme-cli](https://www.mankier.com/package/nvme-cli) commandline tool. It might help you to get it aligned.

**Edit**

As sudodus suggested I'd like to clarify my answer. Instead of using the fsck command (or the equivalent in gparted) to format a nvme, the nvme-cli command offers command to do so.

[nvme-format](https://www.mankier.com/1/nvme-format),which is part of the nvme-cli suite, will format a namespace (partition).In addition multiple different analyze commands will narrow down the problem of your nvme.

I'm using a nvme on debian, which I had to format with this tool during setup (that was 4 years ago), because the standard tools did not work....

See the [debian man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/nvme-cli/nvme-format.1.en.html) as well

Comment: If you can, please help the original poster with more details or a dialogue how to use the tools/methods that you link to.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I may be misunderstanding but won't nvme-format erase all data? I would ideally like to fix my system without having to start from scratch so that wouldn't be a viable option.