# Cannot delete directory that is owned by "?"

Tags: filesystem

I'm on ext4. I have a rogue directory here:

```
d?????????  ? ?        ?                       ?            ? thisStrangeDirectory/
```

As root, I can't chmod, chown or stat the directory... it just permission denied to absolutely everything.

Tried:
`lsattr /home/june/thisStrangeDirectory` (Suggested by paladin)
Got: `lsattr: Permission denied while trying to stat /home/june/thisStrangeDirectory`

What can I do with this thing?

Comment: Make a complete filesystem check first. And make sure that this file/directory has not +i attribute (viewable with `lsattr FILENAME`). You may remove this attribute with `sudo chattr -i FILENAME`.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Did you try with sudo?

Comment: Check & repair the file system. What file system is it? `ext4`, NTFS, FAT32 or something else?

Comment: @David This is occurring while I'm root. Also tried sudo just to do it.

Comment: @paladin Thanks for your suggestion . Tried it but still perm denied.

Comment: This won't be fixed with normal tools: it is a filesystem error. I assume this is not a mountpoint? If not you need to check the filesystem. see for instance https://askubuntu.com/a/1237483/15811

Comment: So the bad file seems to be in your home directory. There is probably an `ext4` file system. Boot from another Ubuntu drive, I suggest a USB pendrive with Ubuntu live (the system, that you used to install Ubuntu). Identify the partition where you have your home directory with `lsblk -f` and `df /home` and repair it. [This link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986) may be helpful.